# Can Doccano UI be shown in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, doccano

I saw a video called 'Deep Learning with Unstructured Text' and in which they were using doccano an open source annotation tool for ML. In that video they were using the doccano UI in the Jupyter Notebook itself. I saw the video but they did not mention how they were using the UI in notebook.

Does anybody knows how that works?

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YdMSQSRGPk&ab_channel=EsriEvents)

Please go to 20:47 timestamp.

Also attaching image for reference:
[image]

Comment: also looking for same. Any help?